# Find Bandwidth usage on app engine subdomains mappend on the same service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bandwidth, google-app-engine, statistics

I have sole problem find bandwidth usage logs about different domains.
This is the infrastructure:

Domains mapped:

1. **example.com**
2. **example2.com**
3. **example3.com**
4. ... **example10.com**
   and every subdomain with wildcard, for example **domain.example.com** and so on.

All this domains, are mapped on the same App Engine, we will call this service "appengine".

We need to know **all bandwidth for each one, including bandwidth used on Google Clouds Bucket.**

Because we are using the same service for all domains, we can't find that, we can see only request made on application inside the logs but without any information about the requests made on bucket by appengine.

There is some way to get all information? We can "build" some "tags" on request to handle this problem?

Thank you

Comment: 1) Google does not track access based upon domain names, only services. 2) Review App Engine logging https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/writing-application-logs 3) Google does not track public access to Cloud Storage. Google does provide aggregate usage in the billing reports. 4) I am not aware of any tagging that Google tracks for access. You will have to implement that yourself in your own code/logging/reporting system.

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine do not assign a static amount of bandwidth, instead it will escalate depending of the use or the demand of the domain the App engine, [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Requests) you can see how the incoming and out coming bandwidth are describe on the App engine service, and [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/appengine/quotadetails?_ga=2.129558540.1469256949.1619423082-1960619141.1618481082) you can see the quotas of the App Engine service